# Jquery ajax autocomplete plugin

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi i found this plugin to the best upto now. And to what i want
[jQuery Plugin: Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/)

But when i tried to make my own php file with it doesnt works

My php file :

```
<?php
$arr= array(
array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Ruby"),
array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Kritya")
);
var_dump($arr);
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
$json_response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
echo $json_response;
?>
```

They gave me an sample.php file which had this:

```
<?

#
# Example PHP server-side script for generating
# responses suitable for use with jquery-tokeninput
#

# Connect to the database
mysql_pconnect("host", "username", "password") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Could not select database");

# Perform the query
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name from mytable WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 10", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

# Collect the results
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

# Optionally: Wrap the response in a callback function for JSONP cross-domain support
if($_GET["callback"]) {
    $json_response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
}

# Return the response
echo $json_response;

?>
```

I dont want it to get data from a database but just use an array or get data from xml file when i try to use this on the HTML page

```
<h2 id="theme">Facebook Theme</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="blah2" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("/test.php", {
            theme: "facebook"
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

It works fine when i put their website php file but keeps on saying Searching.... With my file Defiantly there is some error with my ARRAY structure.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are passing nestled arrays

```
   $arr= array(
   array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Ruby"),
   array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Kritya")
   );
```

when your plugin expects an array which wraps up a bunch of objects from the **mysql_fetch_object** command.

Perhaps this might work:

```
   $arr=array();
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->id = 1;
   $object->name = "Ruby";
   $arr[]=$object;
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->id = 1;
   $object->name = "Kritya";
   $arr[]=$object;
```